# how to create or rewrite files in wordpress plugin folder

Tags: plugins, contact, wp-filesystem

i'm developing my own plugin. in that i used a simple php file to generate contact vcards in the plugin folder. for this i used fopen & fwrite. but the file is not creating in the plugin folder. this is my code:

```
function Vcard(){
$path =EMAIL_PLUGIN_URL.'/MyFile.txt';
$Handle = (file_exists($path))? fopen($path, "a+") : fopen($path, "w+");
$sql="select the rows from my db";
$rs =/* db array result*/
 while(until the last result) {
 $Data="BEGIN:VCARD"."\n"."VERSION:2.1"."\n";  $Data.="N:".$row['eemail_name_sub'].';'."\n"."FN:".$row['eemail_name_sub']."\n";
$Data.="TEL;CELL:".'+91'.$row['eemail_mobile_sub']."\n"."END:VCARD"."\n";
 fwrite($Handle, $Data);
 }
fclose($Handle); 
$p="data written";
 return $p;
}
```

What may be the reason for this? also how can i download this vcard at the same moment after it is created and written?

Comment: Does `fopen()` call work at all (not return false)? Why do you need to save these files? From personal experience vcards are easier to just generate and serve on the fly.

Comment: there is a list of patient numbers and names and i need to integrate those numbers to phone contacts. for that one method i thought is to generate .vcf files so that it would be easier for syncing with phone contacts. the php file works in separately run but when i paste the file in plugin folder fopen is not creating file